# How to describe a person who has done well in every task except one, but he has done extremely bad in that 'one' task

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I mean, "How to describe a person who has done well in every task except one, but he has done extremely bad in that 'one' task **which adversely affects the overall result.**
I don't literally mean one though.

For example, someone gets extremely good marks in every subject (except one) in school -- he's the top scorer in each individual subject (except one) --  but he's got extremely low marks in one of them, and as a result he's no more first. 
We can say he is *inconsistent*. But it's not exactly what the condition is. It doesn't emphasize the extremeness. *Bottleneck* is another word which I think could be used. But how do we say it -- "*He made a bottleneck*?"

I'd prefer the word/phrase which fills the following blank:
***"He is ____."***

Answer (score 100):

He has an **Achilles heel**.  This implies that his excellence is crippled by a single, titanic flaw.

Apologies for the wiki-link, but the OED didn't capture the full meaning.
[Link-Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles%27_heel)

Answer (score 29):

You could say *He has a **tragic flaw***

> A flaw in the character of the protagonist of a tragedy that brings the protagonist to ruin or sorrow.

*American Heritage Dicitonary*

A more technical (and classical) term is *[hamartia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hamartia)*. *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Similarly, the term *[fatal flaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamartia)* is also used. *Wikipedia*

Answer (score 27):

One might say he has "**a blind spot**", which in this sense is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blind%20spot) as " an area in which one fails to exercise judgment or discrimination".

Comment: Say I'm very bad in painting, but still I think I'm an excellent painter. If I'm not aware of this, then I would call that a blind spot. "Weak spot" would fit the situation better I think. Still, Achilles heel would be my preferred answer.

Answer (score 16):

He is **just short of perfect**?

Or something like... "a blemish on an otherwise perfect record."

Answer (score 3):

Depending on details of the context, you might say this person
**has feet of clay**.

From [Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/have-feet-of-clay):

> have feet of clay
>
> to have a ​bad ​quality that you ​keep ​hidden: *Some of the ​greatest ​geniuses in ​history had ​feet of ​clay.*

Often the "feet of clay" refer to a hidden character flaw, but they *can* refer
to any other shortcoming that is unexpected.
Compare the definition from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feet-of-clay):

> feet of clay
>
> noun
>
> 1. a weakness or hidden flaw in the character of a greatly admired or respected person: *He was disillusioned to find that even Lincoln had feet of clay.*
> 2. any unexpected or critical fault.

Note, however, that all these definitions imply that the weakness was
somehow hidden or unexpected. So if it was known from the very beginning
that a person was a virtuoso in all subjects at school but one,
and that he or she was bound to fail in that one subject, "feet of clay"
may not be the most apt expression.
If the idea is that most people think this person a very good student,
and that the poor performance in one subject is somehow surprising or
difficult to reconcile with the student's other abilities,
"feet of clay" might be a suitable description.

One other connotation of the phrase is that this one weakness in the person
will lead to their ultimate downfall in some way (similar to an Achille's heel).
This particular connotation *does* fit the case of a student who would have
been first in his or her class if not for one subject.
From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feet+of+clay):

> feet of clay
>
> A flaw or vulnerability of someone who is otherwise admirable. In the Bible's Book of Daniel, King Nebuchadnezzar dreamed that he saw a statue made of gold, silver, and brass, but with feet of clay. Daniel interpreted the vision to mean that the clay symbolized the Babylonian Empire's vulnerability and imminent collapse. (See Achilles' heel.)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Dan the comments to [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278676/3347), you could say he is [Napoleonic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Napoleonic)<sup>[1]</sup>.  However, there are a lot of ways one could resemble Napoleon, so it would be better to stretch your one-word criteria a bit and say:

> He met his [Waterloo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/waterloo)<sup>[2]</sup>.

<sub>Suggested by Doug Warren and refined by RemarkLima in other comments on the answer linked above.</sub>

This indicates a pattern of success that was ended due to one "battle", and the metaphor is readily apparent to anyone who understands the reference.  (Napoleon won around 60 battles prior to Waterloo and while [he lost around 6 others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleonic_Wars#cite_note-19) they were not so final.)

Answer (score 0):

To say that he isn't suited to the full set of tasks required.

> He is incomplete.

To say that he fails at a critical moment.

> He is a choke artist.

Answer (score 0):

For a person who is obviously talented and gifted at what they do, but performs poorly on the last or final task you could say:

> 1. He *failed to deliver the goods* on the given day

The Free Dictionary defines the [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/deliver+the+goods) as

> **deliver the goods**
>   if someone or something delivers the goods, they do what people hope they will do
>
> - *So far the team's new player has failed to deliver the goods. He hasn't scored in his first five games*.

I would be more charitable and suggest that the person simply had **a bad day** (at the office).

> 2. Lewis Hamilton blames 'bad day at the office' after finishing sixth in Hungary
>      <sub>source: [Sky Sports](http://www.skysports.com/f1/news/24181/9925585/lewis-hamilton-said-he-had-a-bad-day-at-the-office-after-finishing-sixth-in-hungary)</sub>

Answer (score -4):

*"He is **exceptional but fallible**."*

'Fallible' can indicate that there exists a weak area or areas, and is generally used in a context were the subject is otherwise extraordinary. If you want to underscore past history in failing:

*"He is **exceptional but demonstrably fallible**."*

(Or 'historically' or some other word modifying 'fallible' to indicate past experiences leading to that conclusion.)

Comment: Fallible means that one is capable of making mistakes, but does not imply that you *did* make a mistake.  An expert can be fallible, but that doesn't mean they've given a wrong answer yet, much less to a question that would lead to a major negative impact.

Comment: @Doc By the same logic, 'Achilles Heel' (the current winning-by-a-landslide favorite) *also* is incorrect.  Having an Achilles Heel means you have a giant weakness when you're otherwise invulnerable, but not that you've screwed up in the past. Achilles had his hell *before* getting shot with an arrow.

Comment: True, but there is a distinction.  If I said that John is an expert on bomb defusal, but he *is* fallible, one would expect that they can talk to him about it and be fairly confident in his response.  If, on the other hand, I said that he's an expert on bomb defusal but that defusing one with an alarm clock as a component was his Achilles Heel?  You could be damn sure that people wouldn't ask him to defuse such a bomb (or for advice on how to defuse it).  Fallible doesn't mean much but imperfect.  Achilles Heel implies much more of a devastating weakness.

Comment: Your original comment implied that the issue was that 'fallible' could not (explicitly) be historically verified, not that it's generality or specificity was at issue.